# Lost java object identity after creating my own toString method

Tags: java, identity

assume I have my own linkedlist implementation:

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}
```

When I have this simple setup, I can use a node in a Map:

```
ListNode A = new ListNode(1);
ListNode B = new ListNode(2);
ListNode C = new ListNode(3);
A.next = B;
B.next = C;

Map<ListNode, Integer> hmp = new HashMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(A, 1)
));
```

When I print the Map object, I got:

```
System.out.println(hmp);
// >>> {ListNode@57829d67=1}
```

However, after I implement a toString method for my linkedlist, so that I can print it out straightforwardly:

```
public String toString() {
    if (this.next != null) {
        return this.val + "->" + this.next.showString();
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(A.val);
    }
}
```

Now If I can print the linked list nicely, but if I print the Map again:

```
System.out.println(A);
// >>> 1->2->3
System.out.println(hmp);
// >>> {1->2->3=1}
```

You can see that I lost the original way of showing the identity of the `ListNode` object in map.

1. Is there any way to fix this?
2. Is there a method that I can call to ListNode to show `ListNode@57829d67` ?

The only that I can see is not to override the toString method but create a different method to show the string of my linkedlist object. I am not sure if this is a good idea

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is **not** an "identity"; it is the `hashCode()` of your `ListNode`. Call `hashCode()` to get the "57829d67" whenever you want.

Comment: Well but then why `toString` method would change how a `Map` got print out?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 See [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). The javadoc says (in part) *The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character "@", and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

 `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`*

Comment: Ok, so is it a good idea that I don't override this `toString`, but maybe I can create my own `showString` method to show what I want to see, and leave this `toString` as it is?